# Taking value from text-field and sending it with AJAX request Javascript

Tags: ajax, server, client

I am trying to sync both client-side and server-side scripts that the client intakes a value from the textbox and sends it to the server, upon which the server displays that input as a cookie.

Here is the code that I have so far

```
function loadCookie() {
        //[1] make a new request object
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        //[2] set the request options
        xhttp.open("GET", "index.html", true);

        //[3] define what you will do when you ge a response (callback)
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("input_response").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };

        //[4] finally send out the request
        xhttp.send();
    }
```

I have the  and the button but I am having issue of the page re-loading itself instead of taking the value of the input and showing it as a cookie in the server. I'm suspecting it is having to do with the URL by the index.html